# Spring Boot: How do I know if an Application was interrupted in @PreDestroy Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I there any way to find out if the `@PreDestroy` Method in a Spring Boot Application was called because `CTRL-C` was pressed or `kill <PID>` was called?

I want to differ from the case that the Application regularly stops. (No Daemon, No Web Server)

#### Background:

I'm using Spring Boot as an Runner that is started in a Docker Container by a schedule. The App does it work and closes itself. The `kill <PID>` occurs when `docker stop <containerid>` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own aspect to log any `@PreDestroy` execution

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(javax.annotation.PreDestroy)")
    public Object logPreDestroyExecution(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
       // ...
       // get info from joinPoint and log
       // ...
       return joinPoint.proceed();
    } 
}
```

More detailed example: [Spring AOP + AspectJ](https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)

Comment: I'm not using AspectJ. But I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I realized that it should be better to log execution inside `@PreDestroy` method. Adding new aspect might be an overkill. Note: Spring will not call the `@PreDestroy` for prototype beans.